# how to add listview in listview in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

i adding in listview item as 3 textview and i want to display listview item with 3 text view and listview.I am doing like these...

```
  <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seating_people_sno_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Sno"
            android:textColor="#e73e97"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seating_tname_txt"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Table Name"
            android:textColor="#e73e97"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seating_seats_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Seating"
            android:textColor="#e73e97"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seating_seated_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Seated"
            android:textColor="#e73e97"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seating_add_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Add"
            android:textColor="#e73e97"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="#c6c6c6" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/seatingchart_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#c6c6c6"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
```

in these xml contain listview for listview i add one more xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seatingparentlist_sno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#595959" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seatingparentlist_tablename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seatingparentlist_sno"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#595959" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seatingparentlist_seating"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seatingparentlist_tablename"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#595959" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seatingparentlist_seated"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seatingparentlist_seating"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#595959" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/seatingparentlist_addbtn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seatingparentlist_seated"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<ListView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:divider="#c6c6c6"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/seatingparentlist_list">
</ListView>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

i am using one more listview in these xml for these list view i am using one more xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detailseating_list_peoplename"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#595959"
            android:text="sai.."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detailseating_list_brideorgroom"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#595959"
            android:text="sai.."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" /> 

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/detailseating_list_rsvp_img"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:textColor="#595959"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:src="@drawable/cancelicon"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" /> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

these must me using in single activity if any have idea please help me

Comment: Please be specific while asking question.I am not getting your requirement what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I want listview item with another listview.

Comment: then Rajkiran has answer will be useful for you.

Comment: In one of your xml i saw you used listview inside scrollview.Donot do that listview comes with default scrolling capability.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is [Expandable ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

They've also given an example in API demos.

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify [Jeff Sharkey's](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) approach of making a sectioned list, to suit your needs.

As you want a list to be in another list, why don't you set the other list's adapter as an adapter element to your main list?

This is how it can be done,

Make a custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter then

```
 MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(Your Context here);  
        adapter.addAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "Text1", "Text2" }));  

        ListView mainList = new ListView(Context);  
        list.setAdapter(adapter);  
        this.setContentView(list);
```

That should do it...

Answer (score 1):

this is the good way to make custome listview for that.you can easily get demo for that.if not getting the result then try api demo for android.many demos are there so