# How to put ListView inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, layout

All,

I have a screen on which I used a RelativeLayout. Unfortunately, the information that needs to be displayed is big and so in order for it to be scrollable I put the layout in a ScrollView.

Now this screen should contain a ListView in it. But trying to put a ListView inside a Relativelayout tag in xml gives me an error in Eclipse: "Vertically scrolling ScrollView should not contain another vertically scrolling widget (ListView)".

Upon searching I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817165/how-to-add-listview-in-listview-in-android) but the RelativeLayout I'm using does not contain an array.

Is there any other solution to this problem/error?

Thank you.

[EDIT]

A little clarification. The outer list view is not based on the Array or any other collection. It just a big set of properties for one specific item. Now the inner list view is a list of items that is related to this particular one. Moreover all those properties should always be visible on the screen in the form of:

```
Property_name         Property_value
```

where both property_name and property_value are TextView's.

Hopefully this makes it more clear of what I need to have.

[/EDIT]

[EDIT 2]

Here is what my layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image"
            android:contentDescription="@string/product_picture"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_image"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FF909090" 
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_price_text"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:text="@string/product_price_text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/line1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price_with_discount"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/line1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_price"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
             android:layout_below="@id/line1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/line2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_price_text"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FF909090" 
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_category_text"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:text="@string/product_category_text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/line2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_product_category"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/line2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/line3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_category_text"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FF909090" 
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_code_text"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:text="@string/product_code_text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/line3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_product_code"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_below="@id/line3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/line4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_code_text"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FF909090" 
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_availability_text"
        android:text="@string/product_availability_text"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/line4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_availability"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/line4"
    />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/line5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_availability_text"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FF909090" 
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_dimensions_text"
        android:text="@string/product_dimensions_text"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/line5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/product_dimensions"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/line5"
    />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/line6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_dimensions_text"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FF909090" 
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_weight_text"
        android:text="@string/product_weight_text"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/line6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/product_weight"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/line6"
    />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/line7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_weight_text"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FF909090" 
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_color_text"
        android:text="@string/product_color_text"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/line7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/product_color"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/line7"
    />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/line8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_color_text"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FF909090" 
    />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/product_quantity"
        android:text="@string/default_quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/line8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:inputType="number"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/product_add_to_cart"
        android:text="@string/add_to_cart"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/product_quantity"
        android:layout_below="@id/line8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_description_text"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/product_description_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_description"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_description_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_related_products_text"
        android:text="@string/product_related_products_text"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_description"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/product_related_products"
    >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is an xml file for an activity. As you can see I have a lot of stuff for the product itself (image, name, color, size, etc). All this is for 1 product, NOT AN ARRAY OF PRODUCTS. And then in the end (bottom) I'd like to display related products, or products from the same category.

[/EDIT2]

Answer (score 4):

You shouldnt try to put a ListView in a listview. Its just not going to work.
Instead I'd recommend using an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), here is a [tutorial](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html)

Comment: what I have here is a screen which displays an information about one single item (screenshot, name, description, price, etc.). Underneath I need to display the list view of the related products to this particular one. So ExpandableListView is not what I need. Any other suggestions? (What I mean is: Outer list is not an Array (Collection) - just a huge list of properties).

Comment: @Igor It sounds like you are trying to display too much information in a single Activity. You might want to redesign your app to include a subview that shows more details. In order to provide more specific suggestions, we need more information.

Comment: @Code-Guru, added layout.xml for an activity.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to display too much information in a single view. I suggest that you create a UI design that breaks this activity into multiple activities each with manageable chunks of data. [Application Structure](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/app-structure.html) is a great place to start with some ideas for how to structure your app.

Comment: If I remove the ScrollView, I will not be able to see the whole information. Only part will be visible. I have about 10 text view that lays out vertically with the image view on top. Without ScrollView only the image and 3-4 text view is visible and no possibility to scroll. On top of that after those text views there is a list view which gives an error.

Comment: @Igor Are you saying that there are more widgets in the ScrollView than just the ListView? I suggest that you provide a simple example of an XML layout to illustrate. It doesn't have to be as big as what you actually have in your app. Just enough to show what you want to do.

Comment: added xml for an activity.